Pulseaudio combine microphone and app audio into one
I have a microphone, headphones, an app that is playing sounds and an app that accepts sound input (ex: discord). I want it so that the app is both playing the sound to my headphones and combining with my microphone to go into the app as sound input. Attached diagram to communicate what I mean:

Mic - microphone, App - some app which outputs sound, Other app - another app that outputs sound that I want to hear but not use, Mic* - combination of my microphone and the App's output, ex: discord - some app that accepts audio input.

I assume you're asking how to implement that. qpwgraph lets you just connect arbitrary output streams to inputs on applications.
If you want to set this up more permanently, you'd follow the guide on https://docs.pipewire.org/page_module_loopback.html (because you're almost certainly not using pulseaudio, but pipewire, which is pretty much completely compatible).
